# Trying to change an SKSpriteNode image using a variable

Tags: swift, swift2, skspritenode

So I recently started using a struct to hold variables that define my achievement so that it makes it easier to access. as seen below:

```
struct Achieve {

var aName:String = ""
var aDes:String = ""
var aImage:String = ""
var aAmount:Int = 0
var aRequired:Int = 0

}
```

So I defined a variable called 'Ach1' like so:

```
var Ach1 = Achieve(aName: "No. Games", aDes: "Games Played", aImage: "locked", aAmount: 0, aRequired: 10)
```

and then I created an SKSpriteNode using the function below:

```
func generateShopItems (location: CGPoint, page:SKSpriteNode, tex: String) -> SKSpriteNode {

        let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: tex)
        node.position = location
        page.addChild(node)
        return node
}
```

Then I used the Ach1 variable's aImage property as the tex string when defining the SKSpritenode in another function like below

```
Achievements.append(generateShopItems(CGPointMake(-120, 200), page:(page1ScrollView), tex: Ach1.aImage))
```

The texture comes out fine when the game is run for the first time but i can't get the image to change when I change the Ach1 variables aImage property in my touches method it just stays the same.

```
} else if (node == Achievements[7]) {

        Ach1.aImage = "diamondicon"
         print("working")

}
```

I need to be able to change the image of the SKSpriteNode while the game is being played. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
var Ach1 = Achieve(node: SKSpriteNode?, aName: "No. Games", aDes: "Games Played", aImage: "locked", aAmount: 0, aRequired: 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that comes to my mind first. It may not be the best, but it's not bad either.

In your `Achieve` struct, add a property called `node`:

```
var node: SKSpriteNode?
```

And change the `aImage` property to look something like this:

```
var aImage: String = "" {
    didSet {
        node?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: aImage)
    }
}
```

Now when you generate the nodes, replace this:

```
Achievements.append(generateShopItems(CGPointMake(-120, 200), 
    page:(page1ScrollView), tex: Ach1.aImage))
```

with this

```
var node = generateShopItems(CGPointMake(-120, 200), 
    page:(page1ScrollView), tex: Ach1.aImage)
Achievements.append(node)
Ach1.node = node
```

Now when you change the `aImage` property of `Ach1`, the node's texture should change as well.

Comment: I get an error when defining Ach1 variable because It asks me to set something for node which i don't know what to put except for SKSpriteNode?, I have edited my answer with it.

Comment: @Astrum Oh I forgot about that. Just put `nil`.

Comment: Thanks that seem to have done the job. would have there been another way to do it without creating a node variable? like maybe using the update function to change the image?

Comment: Well yes you can. But that just seems a little excessive to me. The `update` function is called several times per second, but the texture only needs changing when `aImage` is changed. @Astrum

Comment: I only ask because i'm going to have more than one achievement SKspritenode in the future and would like an easier way of updating the image on all of them.

Comment: could you also take a look at this other question i have about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176379/updating-an-sklabel-to-show-the-right-integer

Comment: @Astrum Your new question is almost the same as this one, you know. Just try to apply the solution! Tip: it would be faster if you do it yourself.